# Convert hexadecimal string to unsigned char[]

Tags: c, windows

I want to convert a string, say "00-00-CA-FE-BA-BE" to unsigned char ch[6] array. I have tried using `sscanf`, but for whatever reason it crashes due to stack corruption after variable macAddress.

I am guessing there is some gotcha with the format specifier, but I can't seem to get it right.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char string1[] = "00-00-CA-FE-BA-BE";
char seps[]   = "-";
char *token1 = NULL;
char *next_token1 = NULL;

int main( void )
{
    unsigned char macAddress[6];
    unsigned char ch;
    int idx=0;
    printf( "Tokens:\n" );

    // Establish string and get the first token:
    token1 = strtok_s( string1, seps, &next_token1);

    while ((token1 != NULL))
    {
        sscanf_s(token1, "%02X", &macAddress[idx++], 1);
        printf(" idx %d : %x\n", idx, macAddress[idx-1]);
        token1 = strtok_s( NULL, seps, &next_token1);
    }
}
```

I would be glad if someone could find the problem or suggest an alternative.

Comment: Add logging and see how far it gets, where it crashes, and whether it does what you expect.

Comment: Just to add the exact error I get is "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'macAddress' was corrupted". 

The other thing i did was to increase the size of the array from 6->7 and the exe stopped crashing. So i am guessing "02x" format specifier is writing 2 bytes instead of 1?

Comment: I am looking for C. (i removed the c++ tag, sorry about that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The %X format specifier is for integers, not characters. You need to pass the address of an integer variable to `sscanf_s` whose value you later assign to a character.

Comment: is there a wait to directly convert from hex string to unsigned char? The intermediate step of converting to an int before typecasting to unsigned char seems unnecessary.

Comment: Personally, I would just write a function to do it and avoid any `scanf`-type function.

Comment: @slowstart: strtol(char*, char**, base)

Answer (score 1):

In C++ I'd probably use a stringstream, something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned char> macAddress;

    std::istringstream input("00-00-CA-FE-BA-BE");

    unsigned int temp;

    // read first byte of input.
    input >> std::hex >> temp;

    do {
        // save current byte
        macAddress.push_back((unsigned char) temp);
        // ignore separator
        input.ignore(1);
        // read next byte:
    } while (input >> std::hex >> temp);

    // show what we read:
    for (auto ch : macAddress)
        std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned int) ch << ":";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To scan a MAC address in to an array of 6 `unsigned char`:

```
const char string1[] = "00-00-CA-FE-BA-BE";
unsigned char macAddress[6];
char c;
int n;
n = sscanf(string1, "%hhX-%hhX-%hhX-%hhX-%hhX-%hhX %c", &macAddress[0],
        &macAddress[1], &macAddress[2], &macAddress[3], &macAddress[4],
        &macAddress[5], &c);
if (n == 6) {
  printf("%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X\n", macAddress[0], macAddress[1],
          macAddress[2], macAddress[3], macAddress[4], macAddress[5]);  // 00-00-CA-FE-BA-BE
} 
else {
  printf("Oops %d\n", n);
}
```

Comment: this has the same problem as my original code and will crash unless you use 'unsigned int []'.

Comment: @slowstart: Only because you're using MSVC which is broken and does not accept the `%hhx` conversion specifier (it ignores the `hh`). On a proper standard library implementation, this answer works fine.

Comment: @slowstart This does not crash on my Widows machine - work fines.  Are you using a C compiler that that is at least C99 compliant?

Comment: @chux: `%hhx` with `unsigned char` still causes a stack corruption with VS2013. This is in a C++ program, mind.